# Java program not using new value after a change from a mutator

Tags: java

I must have 2 classes and I have to do it based off of my professor's "skeletal" version of `testPayroll`.  I have used as many of the ideas that were given to me already.  I need to use the mutator to increase the hours by 10.  I then have to recalculate that employee's salary (rate * hours).  Finally have have to add the new salary of `e1` to the salary of `e2`.

It appears that I now have the adding part right, but now it seems that the new salary for `e1` is just using the salary for `e2`. I have a feeling this is something really simple. I have been working on this and researching since 6AM this morning :(

Here is the first Class: Payroll

```
public class Payroll {

  static double salary;
  static double payout;

  private String employee_number;
  private int hours;
  private double hourly_rate;

  public Payroll(String num, int hrs, double rate){
    this.employee_number = num;
    this.hours= hrs;
    this.hourly_rate = rate;

    salary = hrs*rate;
    payout = salary + salary;

  }

  public String getNum() {return employee_number;}
  public double getHrs() {return hours;}
  public double getRate(){return hourly_rate;}

  public static double getTotalPayout() {return payout;}
  public static double getSalary() {return salary;}
  public void increaseHrs(int amount) {hours+=amount;}

}
```

Here is the TestPayroll:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

class TestPayroll {

  public static void main(String[]args){

    Date d = new Date();
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    System.out.println("Payroll For Week Ending "+df.format(d));
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");

    Payroll e1 = new Payroll("444-4444",30,25);
    e1.getSalary();
    displaySalary(e1,nf);
    System.out.println("Employee # ...... "+e1.getNum());
    System.out.println("Hours worked .... "+e1.getHrs()+" hours");
    System.out.println("Hourly rate ..... "+e1.getRate()+"/hour");
    System.out.println("Your salary is .. "+nf.format(e1.getSalary()));
    System.out.println("------------------------------------\n");

    Payroll e2 = new Payroll("555-5555",20,25);
    e2.getSalary();
    displaySalary(e2,nf);
    System.out.println("Employee # ...... "+e2.getNum());
    System.out.println("Hours worked .... "+e2.getHrs()+" hours");
    System.out.println("Hourly rate ..... "+e2.getRate()+"/hour");
    System.out.println("Your salary is .. "+nf.format(e2.getSalary()));
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");

    e1.increaseHrs(10);
    e1.getSalary();
    displaySalary(e1,nf);
    System.out.println("Increase "+e1.getNum()+ " by 10 hours");
    System.out.println("Employee # ...... "+e1.getNum());
    System.out.println("Hours worked .... "+e1.getHrs()+" hours");
    System.out.println("Hourly rate ..... "+e1.getRate()+"/hour");
    System.out.println("Your salary is .. "+nf.format(e1.getSalary()));
    System.out.println("------------------------------------\n");

    System.out.println("Total payout amount .. 
    "+nf.format(Payroll.getTotalPayout()));
    System.out.println("------------End of Report-----------\n");
  }

  public static void displaySalary(Payroll e,NumberFormat nf){
  }
}
```

Here is the program run:

```
Payroll For Week Ending May 16, 2018
------------------------------------
Employee # ...... 444-4444
Hours worked .... 30.0 hours
Hourly rate ..... 25.0/hour
Your salary is .. $750.00
------------------------------------

Employee # ...... 555-5555
Hours worked .... 20.0 hours
Hourly rate ..... 25.0/hour
Your salary is .. $500.00
------------------------------------
Increase 444-4444 by 10 hours
Employee # ...... 444-4444
Hours worked .... 40.0 hours
Hourly rate ..... 25.0/hour
Your salary is .. $500.00
------------------------------------

Total payout amount .. $1,000.00
------------End of Report-----------
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the semantics of your class structure, and you are using static and instance variables alternatively. You create an instance of `PayRoll` for each employee, which is having instance attributes like `hourlyRate`, `salary`, `hours` and all. And you are tracking the total payout as a static variable `totalPayout`.

When you do this, you need to properly refer to the variables, using `this` keyword. And there was a semantic error in your implementation, which is, every time you increase the hours, you need to add the total for that increment to the total payment, which you have not done. So, what you need to do is something like follows. I have taken the liberty of minifying your example for the sake of simplicity. I hope this will be an example for you to understand what a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.

```
class PayRoll{
    private static double totalPayout;
    public static double salary;

    private int hours;
    private double rate;

    public PayRoll(int hrs, double rate){
        this.rate = rate; // Note the usage of this keyword
        this.hours = hrs;
        totalPayout += (hrs * rate);
    }

    public void increaseHrs(int amount){
        hours += amount;
        totalPayout += (this.rate * amount); // This was not there in yours. also note the use of `this` keyword.
    }

    public static double getTotalPayout(){
        return totalPayout;
    }
}

class PayRollRun{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        PayRoll e1 = new PayRoll(30, 25);
        PayRoll e2 = new PayRoll(40, 25);
        System.out.println(PayRoll.getTotalPayout());
        e1.increaseHrs(10);
        System.out.println(PayRoll.getTotalPayout());
    }
}
```

However, I see a lot of flaws in your way of doing this. What I think you should do is, have a `List` of `Employee`s in the `PayRoll` class. So, you will write an employee class separately from `PayRoll` and have a `List` of `Employee` instances in `PayRoll` class.

Comment: To elaborate slightly on this answer (which I think gives you some excellent pointers on where to start), I'd recommend spending some time to understand the difference between instance variables and static variables - look for tutorials and other questions here, it's a topic that is covered far better than I could attempt to. In your example, I'm pretty sure your code would still compile, and might be closer to working if you remove all uses of `static` except in the `PayRollRun.main()` method. If it doesn't - I'd say your first goal should be to get to a point where it does.

Comment: I did the changes as above in my long version and I was able to get the hours to update.  However salary was still using the old figure.  I have that working now as well.  Payout, the 2 salaries together, I was able to piece together with my brother in law's help.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple answer, to your specific question:

> it seems that the new salary for `e1` is just using the salary for `e2`

this is because you have the `salary` in `Payroll` as `static`, i.e. your line:

```
static double salary;
```

would be better written as:

```
private double salary;
```

By making it static, you are sharing the value of `salary` across all instances of `Payroll` - so when you first create `e1`, you set the value to `30 * 25`, then, when you create `e2` you set the value to `20 * 25`. Because `salary` is static, there is only one copy of this value shared by both `e1` and `e2`, so the second time you set it, you update both `e1` *and* `e2`'s salaries to the new value.

Romeo Sierra's answer is much more complete, and a better answer than this one, so you should consider all the points from that answer along with this, but this should resolve the specific issue you have asked about.

Comment: I made the change but one of my getters in the test class wouldn't stop giving me the message that I couldn't call a static from a non-static.  I have this figured out another way but I am sure it isn't the way I am "supposed" to do it for this class.  Thanks for the help!  I get a little less left behind each day!